# How to access Athena/Glue catalog for my Athena tables in eu-west-1 via boto3?

Tags: boto3, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I need to write a job which uses data from my Athena data catalog. I'm using Python and boto3. Since Glue has been released, it seems I access my data catalog via Glue APIs using code such as:

```
import boto3
from pprint import pprint

glue = boto3.client('glue', region_name='us-east-1')

response = glue.get_tables(
    DatabaseName='default'
)

print(pprint(response['TableList']))
```

But this doesn't work for the region eu-west-1, I guess since Glue isn't supported there yet.

How do I access my data catalog for Athena data tables I own in eu-west-1? I think this should be possible since they show up in the UI!

Cross posting this one from AWS Forums:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=269605

Answer (score 2):

Just to bring this to a close. AWS Glue has just been released for eu-west-1 (2017-12-19), so this is no longer an issue.

Zerodf's answer might still be best for users in regions not supported by AWS Glue yet

Comment: FYI...Here is the documentation for the Glue API (it looks very powerful) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need DDL and data source information, my advice would be to [create a paginator](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Paginator.ListQueryExecutions) and then loop through all query executions.  From there, you can pull all of the `CREATE TABLE` statements and parse them according to your needs.

Example of a brute force approach (Python 2):

```
import boto3

# Get a list of Query Execution IDs
client = boto3.client('athena', region_name = 'us-east-1')

paginator = client.get_paginator('list_query_executions')

id_list = [] # List for holding query exection ids

for page in paginator.paginate():
    for id in page['QueryExecutionIds']:
        id_list.append(id)  

# Get a list of query execution metadata
meta_list = []
for id in id_list:
    execution_event = client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId = id)
    meta_list.append(execution)
```

You can now filter the metadata list on the Query string (focusing on statements beginning with `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE`.  You can also organize your data by `context` and `CompletionDateTime`.

If you just need column names and types, then you can run `DESCRIBE database_name.table_name;` and get the column names and types.

Comment: Really helpful, thanks Zerodf. I'm actually hoping to run this periodically, so like you say, this becomes really brute force. The long term solution is I guess to use AWS Glue when it becomes available in eu-west-1, I'm not sure when that will be. Will take a look at whether your solution can work for me...

Comment: thanks again Zerodf, as I added below, Glue is now available in eu-west-1, so I can use the catalog. Cheers